# Script moving the mouse on a virtual machine

Tags: python, virtual-machine, mouseevent, pywin32

I prepared a script which does some operation on a web page, recognize colors and simulate mouse click and keyboard send keys while running. It works fine.

The problem is that I want it to run on a virtual machine (I'm trying greencloudvps) and it works fine as long as have my eyes on it.

As soon as I close the "remote desktop connection" tool, the script crashes, because (I guess) there is no more a monitor where to move the mouse.

I use the following Python code:

```
win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y)) 
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
```

Is there any solution?

UPDATE:i tried to run my script also on Amazon virtual machine but i got the same problem. Which could be the solution?

**Basically I need to click with mouse, read pixel colors and send skeys with keyboard automatically on a virtual machine even when I don’t witness the session, using python**

Comment: What sort of script you are running? e.g. javascript, batch, bash, ...

Comment: it's a python script and it use following commands:
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y)) // win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)

Comment: This is pretty common problem. Can be resolved several ways. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47142927/3648361

Comment: thanks for your comments. unfortunately i have to use on the GUI of server the mouse also in automatic way... therefore methods 1 and 3 does not work... method 2 makes the script crash when I close RDP; method 3(tightVNC) cannot be used because greencloudvps does not allow the use of thightVNC

Comment: Do you need real mouse moving/clicking or just doing some actions with GUI elements? There are few ways to send window messages or calling UI Automation patterns without active desktop available. It can be done by pywinauto.

Comment: I need of mouse click on certain x,y coordinates, mouse clicking, keyboard send keys and color of pixel reading in certain position. Around internet i found that I could create an internal RDP service on the server to keep the GUI active. How Can I do that?          I tried launching a rdp session on the server using IP 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.2 or <the server ip> but a window saying "access denied" appeared.   Any suggestion?

Comment: solved changing server and using tightVNC